# how to handle multiple namespaces with different URI in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML (first.xml) which looks like ::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <saw:jobInfo xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1">     
      <saw:jobStats>...........</saw:jobStats>    
       <saw:detailedInfo> .....</saw:detailedInfo>    
       <saw:fileInfo>..........</saw:fileInfo>
 </saw:jobInfo>
```

The below XML (second.xml) is same as the above but with a different namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <soap:jobInfo xmlns:soap="urn://bi.webservices/v6">  
   <soap:jobStats>...........</saw:jobStats>
   <soap:detailedInfo> .....</saw:detailedInfo>    
   <soap:fileInfo>..........</saw:fileInfo>
 </soap:jobInfo>
```

As I have the same element and attribute names in both the xml's I am using the same xsd file to validate both.

XSD file ::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
 <xs:schema targetNamespace="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1"      
  xmlns="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" 
  xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" 
  xmlns:soap="urn://bi.webservices/v6"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

After including xmlns:soap="urn://bi.webservices/v6" the schema validation failed for second.xml saying unkown element "soap:jobinfo". I poked around and found the targetNamespace  value should be same as the namespace URI.
Please let me know how to use the same XSD for two different namespaces having different URIs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. You could, however, if you would be using three XSDs. It would allow you to have all the XSD that matters into one file (Chameleon.XSD), and have two more that simply compose Chameleon.XSD, those two having the namespaces you want.

Chameleon.XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="jobInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="jobStats" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="detailedInfo" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="fileInfo" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

JobInfo1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Chameleon.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

JobInfo2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="urn://bi.webservices/v6" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn://bi.webservices/v6" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Chameleon.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Relationships:

[image: Chameleon relationships]

If you want one XSD to validate them all, then you can go and build a fourth one, that imports these two.

OneAll.XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="urn:tempuri-org:XSD:1" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:tempuri-org:XSD:1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" schemaLocation="JobInfo1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="urn://bi.webservices/v6" schemaLocation="JobInfo2.xsd"/> 
</xsd:schema>
```

Updated relationships:

[image: One all]

Comment: @@Petru: Thanks a lot for the reply. I cann't make a Chameleon.XSD as there are many XSDs. Please explain it with a diagram or with an example so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @prathima, I've alredy updated my response, just timing... If you have really complex schemas that include other namespaces, then you cannot achieve what you want, Chameleon or not. The idea of a chameleon is to assume the namespace of the schema that composes it. So you could have same structures in different namespaces, without having duplication. One thing to remember is that one XSD = one namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The end tags in second.xml need to match the beginning rags (i.e. soap does not equal saw)